# existence of countably additive measure for Borel subsets of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Problem:** **Let $F(x)$ be a continuous and non-decreasing function on $[0,1]$ with $F(0)=0$ and $F(1)=1$.** I'd like to prove the existence of a couuntably additive measure $\mu$ on Borel subsets of $[0,1]$ s.t. $\mu\left([a,b]\right)=F(b)-F(a)$ for all intervals $[a,b]\subset[0,1]$.

I can prove the case when **$F(x)$ is the distribution function**, which is non-decreasing and right continuous on the real line. Then, $F(x)=\mu\left((-\infty,x]\right)$. $\mu\left((a,b]\right)=F(b)-F(a)$.

My sketch of the proof for this case: We need to show that if $(a,b]=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}(a_j,b_j]$, then $F(b)-F(a)=\sum_{j}F(b_j)-F(a_j)$.

$\ge$ is obvious.

For $\leq$, we apply Caratheodory extension for $\mu$ from the semiring of intervals to the Borel $\sigma$-field. By definition of distibution function, $F(x)\to 0$ as $x\to-\infty$. We can replace $a$ by finite number of $a'$ s.t. $F(a')-F(a)<\varepsilon$. Similary, we can replace $b$ by finite $b'$ s.t. $F(b)-F(b')<\varepsilon$. By right continuity of $F(x)$, we can replace $(a_j,b_j]$ by $(a_j,b_j')$ s.t. $F(b_j')-F(b_j)<\frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}$. Now we have
$$F(b')-F(a')\ge F(b)-F(a)-2\varepsilon$$ and $[a',b']\subset(a,b]$ is closed and bounded.

Moreover, $(a_j,b_j')$ is an open cover of $[a',b']$. By Heine-Borel, we can find such finite subcover and
$$\sum_{j}F(b_j)-F(a_j)\ge\sum_{j}F(b_j')-F(a_j)-\frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}\ge F(b')-F(a')-2\varepsilon\ge F(b)-F(a)-3\varepsilon$$
Let $\varepsilon\to 0$ to get the desired result.

**My questions are:**

1. How can I adapt the proof I provided above for the problem I am asking? I am stuck, since countable union of disjoint closed sets may not be a closed set. And the problem seems to be a restriction of the distribution function to the interval $[0,1]$. If so, how? And if not, how can I write a new proof?
2. I am also interested in the case when $F(x)$ has jumps on its domain $[0,1]$. Do I have break into the case on finite and infinite jumps? I know the fact that Dirac measures are countably additive, so does this fact help to prove this case?

**Added(09/13/2020):** I think it is possible for singular points to have non-zero measures. For example in my case, we can define Dirac measure at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, a valid countably additive measure on $\mathcal{B}$. $$F(x)=\chi_{\{[1/2,1]\}}$$ is one such example. Please point out if I have any flaw in my reasoning.

If there is a similar question regarding this, please direct me to that. I know this may be a basic question, but I'd like to receive help on this. Thank you.

Comment: You can't. Take $$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x < 1/2, \\ \frac{1}{2} &\text{if } x = 1/2, \\ 1 &\text{if } x > 1/2. \end{cases}$$ Then various properties of measures force a) $\mu(\{1/2\}) = 0$, b) $\mu(\{1/2\}) = 1/2$, and c) $\mu(\{1/2\}) = 1$. Some additional conditions or some change in requirements is necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the continuity requirement. With that, $F$ is a distribution function, and the usual way works. If you don't know how to deal with distribution functions defined only on an interval, extend it to $\mathbb{R}$ by setting $F(x) = 0$ for $x < 0$ and $F(x) = 1$ for $x > 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Hello, can you write an answer regarding my two question? I don't know how to deal with the closed set $[a,b]$, since distribution function is defined for half-open half-closed intervals. Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your first question. If you have $\mu((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$ you have $\mu([a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$ by continuity. Where does a countable union of disjoint closed sets enter?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Hello, my confusion is how to possibly link my prove for $\mu\left((a,b]\right)=F(b)-F(a)$ to my problem $\mu\left([a,b]\right)=F(b)-F(a)$? And does such countably additive measure exists if $F(x)$ admits jumps in its domain $[0,1]$? Could you possibly write an answer regarding my confusion. That'll clear things up.

Comment: @DanielFischer:Hello, can you write an answer regarding this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112831/discussion-between-mike-and-daniel-fischer).

Comment: I guess the answer is that you can't do so. To apply the extension theorem, you need an algebra, but the collection of finite disjoint union of closed intervals cannot form an algebra. The exercise has typo.

Comment: Basically, we need to define it using $(a,b]$ and then as the above comment, the measure of $[a,b]$ will be immediate.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical This is what I am concerned about $[a,b]$ in this problem in terms of applying Caratheodory extension. Can you write an answer regarding this? Then I can totally understand where I am wrong.

Comment: Click that chat link, I replied to you there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I guess I kind of figure it out. Please let me know if there is any mistake. Basically, you do all the measure theory things over $\mathbb{R}$ firstly, just like the first part your post.

Then, you get a unique Borel measure $\lambda$ on the whole real line $\mathbb{R}$, and the definition of it is $$\lambda((a,b])=F(b)-F(a).$$

Now, restrict $\lambda$ to $[0,1]$. That is, you define $\mu:=\lambda|_{[0,1]}$. But this is not over, you still need to argue why $$\mu([a,b])=F(b)-F(a),$$ since currently the definition is $\mu((a,b])=F(b)-F(a).$

This involves the continuity. As pointed out by you, if the function has jump, you can have a singular measure at a point. This involves the following lemma.

> Lemma: Let $F$ be an increasing and right-continuous function, and $\mu$ to be the measure associated to it. Then, $\mu(\{a\})=F(a)-F(a-)$, $\mu([a,b))=F(b-)-F(a-)$ and $\mu([a,b])=F(b)-F(a-).$

You could find the proof here [http://www.math.ttu.edu/~drager/Classes/01Fall/reals/ans2.pdf](http://www.math.ttu.edu/%7Edrager/Classes/01Fall/reals/ans2.pdf).

However, if you read the proof, you will see that by definition of $F(a-)$, if your function is continuous, then $F(a-)=F(a)$ and therefore, for continuous function, you can arrive conclusion $$\mu([a,b])=F(b)-F(a-)=F(b)-F(a).$$ However, for jump-function, if it is right continuous, then you can only get the lemma, which is a little bit weaker.

For left continuous function, your construction of Borel measure over $\mathbb{R}$ will use $[a,b)$, so the direction will change. You could easily modify the statement and the proof to discuss the left-continuous case, but the idea is the same so I will not bother to write it here.